# Add user's role as a class to all user links

Tags: 7, users

My goal is to attach a users role as a class to their user name anywhere it is displayed so I can color the link based on role.

I can get roles of every displayed user link using `MYTHEME_username_alter`:

```
function MYTHEME_username_alter(&$name, $account) {
  $user = user_load($account->uid);
  // I can get the roles of each user link through $user
}
```

1. Is this the most efficient way to get the role for each user link?
2. What is the best way to go about adding the role as a class to every user link?
3. Am I way off track and overlooking an easier way to complete my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with username_alter. You can only modify the user name string in there. Its probably better to use preprocess. In your theme `template.php`. Do something like this:

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  // Username is linked, use the link_attributes to inject the class or any other attribute
  if (isset($variables['link_path'])) {
    $variables['link_attributes']['class'][] = 'SOME_CLASS';
  }
  // Username is NOT linked, maybe do something else or nothing
  else {
    $variables['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'SOME_CLASS';
  }
}
```

Comment: I kept running into preprocess_user when looking for a solution, thanks for pointing me at the correct preprocess. I figured out a solution using this function, I'll post it since it may help others but I'll accept this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

To add roles as a class to all user links I used the following:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  $user = user_load($variables['account']->uid);

  foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    if (isset($variables['name'])) {
      $variables['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'role-' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $role));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need not do user_load. Use `global $user` and you will have the $user object.

Comment: @arsenelupin That would give every user link the class of the currently logged in user

Comment: Global user and user_load are identical. You are doing an extra load which hurts perfirmance . every time you do a load on the theme layer you nay be doing something wrong.

Comment: Pretend I have a block with 10 different users listed, the goal was to color each user based on their role. `global $user` gives you the currently logged in user's info.  The code above is loading the role for each different user name as it is loaded.  This can't be done with global $user.

Comment: I see well every case is a little different. In any case,I would avoid doing user_load esp if you have listing of user names/ids. You should hook into whatever mechanism you use to generate this list, and add the role to its theme variables and then use the vars in your preprocess. Anyway, this is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I think it's in scope, I'd still like to find the most efficient way to do this.  If I were just doing it in one block that would work, but I need to add the class to EVERY name that is listed on the site ie "whos online, node authors, forums, member list, several different blocks and many other places that shows a user's name.  Would it be more efficient to hook all 10+ modules individually or use the above code?  Is there a way to do it without either `user_load` or hooking every module that outputs an user name?